# Ubuntu 13.04 too slow to boot on good hardware even slower than windows 7

Tags: boot, 13.04

I have a Ubuntu 13.04 installation and windows 7 dual boot on core i3 2.53GHz + 3GB memory,my installation is now  almost 3 months old.The fresh installation was quite snappy(yet slower than 12.04LTS) but now with time ubuntu is booting awfully slow. I have tried everything like preload,cutting down startup applications etc. I even uninstalled a lot of programs that i don't use very often
even then i don't see any difference.It's still slow,even windows 7 is reasonably faster on same machine

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Wubi, Virtual Box, live cd and Dual Boot. Every time the Os runs slow or freezes and crash. According to Ubuntu website. Something to do with (UEFI) and 64Bit downloading. They recommend iso dvd image. Also if you are getting the guy and keyboard symbol , when loading your os from disc. In the begining. You are running in legacy firmware and it may not be 64 bit programing. Ubuntu recommends that it is downloaded with UEFI firmware , for computers 2011 and up. Problem may be in Firmware and what iso disc image DVD , you may be using. Kinda sckechy on this. Hope it helps. I am an Average to advanced user. American Meggatrends bios are UEFI and some older models , predated 2011, Can change or do both , Legacy and UEFI firmware. And can be changed in the bios. Usually under Boot order.

Comment: UEFI is replacement of traditional BIOS firmware on newer computers and 64bit version of ubuntu can be installed on such hardware.But mine is older one.I have reinstalled ubuntu 13.04(32 bit)and it's snappy again.It gets slower with time and i think it has   something to do with "disk fragmentation", may be this is the reason why ubuntu goes slow as disc usage grows.Something similar happens to windows too.